# Nested form (strong parameters) inserting without values (besides id and timestamps)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, activemodel, strong-parameters

I'm building a RESTful API in Rails 4, and having a difficult time with getting Rails to send nested form attributes for a has_one association through to the database.

I believe that my models are set up as they should be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And in my controller, I have:

```
class API::V1::UsersController < API::V1::APIController
  wrap_parameters format: [:json], include: [:email, :address]

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    @user.build_address
    if @user.save
      render :json => @user
    else
      render :json => { :errors => @user.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :address_attributes => [:id, :line1, :line2, :city, :state, :zip])
  end

end
```

When I post the following JSON object...

```
{
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "address": {
        "line1": "123 Fake St",
        "line2": "",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "10000"
    }
}
```

...These parameters are being passed to the controller:

```
Parameters: {"email"=>"test@example.com", "address"=>{"line1"=>"123 Fake St", "line2"=>"", "city"=>"New York", "state"=>"NY", "zip"=>"10000"}, "user"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com", "address"=>{"line1"=>"123 Fake St", "line2"=>"", "city"=>"New York", "state"=>"NY", "zip"=>"10000"}}}
```

And yet, Rails only inserts the timestamps and user_id association into Postgres.

```
                  id                  |               user_id                | line1 | line2 | city | state | zip |         created_at         |         updated_at         
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+------+-------+-----+----------------------------+----------------------------
 f09263ba-2046-446f-b0f3-3030bf3bc23e | 3025d5aa-ed3c-4fac-bae3-24deede59264 |       |       |      |       |     | 2014-07-27 21:21:58.945165 | 2014-07-27 21:21:58.945165
```

Totally stumped---what am I missing?

Comment: Your `JSON` object and your `parameters` looks a bit strange.I don't see any `user hash` in your `JSON`,probably you are missing it.

Comment: The user hash is there, it's just hiding at the end (via wrap_parameters): `"user"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com", "address"=>{"line1"=>"123 Fake St", "line2"=>"", "city"=>"New York", "state"=>"NY", "zip"=>"10000"}}`

Comment: I'm talking about your `JSON` object.It doesn't seem to have `user` hash